# Creating boot floppy (Lubuntu 18.04)

Tags: grub2, floppy

Trying to create a boot floppy (actual, not "virtual").

`grub-mkresuce --help` mentions floppy image, but the option `--image-type floppy` (as mentioned somewhere) does not work.

Just running `grub-mkrescue -o file` creates a 5 Mb file.

How do I create a Grub rescue floppy image on 18.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a barebones and modern image for floppies, you can use `grub-mkimage` from the command line. Here's how:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create an x64, eft-compatible, multi boot image:

   ```
   grub-mkimage -p /boot -o floppy.img -O x86_64-efi multiboot
   ```

   This will create a file named `floppy.img` that is 307,200 bytes in size.
2. Write the image file to the floppy with `dd`:

   ```
   dd if=floppy.img of=/dev/fd0 bs=1k
   ```

   ***Note:** Be sure to replace* `/dev/fd0` *with your actual device if it's different.*
3. Boot with the floppy like its 1996

This should give you a semi-modern bootable floppy with Grub on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can any more. I am not sure but I suspect that the modern Linux kernel won't fit onto a floppy disk any more.

Make sure that you have a bootable Linux USB key with your current version of Lubuntu. If things go wrong, you can use that to re-install the GRUB bootloader and fix your PC.

Comment: I cannot boot from USB stick, only PXE and floppy.

Comment: (1) What computer is this? Make and exact model please. I have not seen a machine that can't in a decade. (2) is your BIOS current? If not, update it. (3) Take a look at the PLOP Boot Manager.